# Python scoping in dict comprehension

Tags: python, scoping, locals

```
>>> x = 'foo'
>>> {0: locals().get('x')}
{0: 'foo'}
>>> {0: locals().get('x' + spam) for spam in ['']}
{0: None}
```

What is the reason for this discrepancy in behaviour?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dict comprehensions and generator comprehensions create their own local scope.  List comprehensions do not in Python 2.x, but do in Python 3.  (Note that your first example is not a dict comprehension.  It's just a literal dict that happens to have an expression as the value for the key 0.)